# Handle join of KStream with KTable when key is missing from KTable

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I recently started experimenting with kafka streams. I have a scenario where I need to join a `KStream` with a `KTable`. It may be the case that the `KTable` does not contain some of the keys. In that case I get a `NullPointerException`.

specifically I was getting

> stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Streams application error during processing: 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I don't know how I can handle that. I cannot somehow filter out the records of the stream that do not correspond to a table entry.

**update**

Looking a bit further I found that I can query the underlying store to find whether a key exists through the `ReadOnlyKeyValueStore` interface.

In this case my question is, would that be the best way to go? i.e. Filtering the stream to be joined based on whether a key exists in the local store?

My second question in this case would be, since I care about leveraging the `Global State Store` introduced in version `10.2` in a next phase, should I expect that I will be also able in the same manner to query the `Global State Store`?

**update**

The previous update is not accurate since it's not possible to query the state store from inside the topology

**final update**

After understanding the join semantics a bit better I was able to solve the issue just be simplifying the `valueJoiner` to only return the results, instead of performing actions on the joined values, and adding an extra filtering step after the join to filter out null values.

Comment: I am still a little puzzled. When do you get the `NullPointerException` exactly? What version of Kafka do you use? What "type" of join do you use (ie, inner or left join)? Also check out this: http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#kstream-ktable-join

Comment: You might want to answer your question by yourself and accept your own answer. Or delete the question after all :)

Comment: I was trying to do a `leftJoin` on the stream. I updated the question with the message I was getting. I am on version `0.10.1`. I will formulate the answer properly and submitted. Thanks :)

Comment: You might want to upgrade to `0.10.2` -- it offers inner KStream-KTable join and thus, there will be no `null` values when `ValueJoiner` get's called. Btw: you don't need to upgrade your brokers for this: http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/upgrade-guide.html#compatibility

Comment: Oh really cool. I hadn't noticed that. yep this simplified things a lot. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to my problem came from understanding the `join` semantics a bit better.

Like in database joins (although I am not saying that `Kstream` joins follow the db join concepts precisely) the left join operation results in rows with null values wherever the right side keys are missing.

So eventually the only thing I had to do was to decouple my `valueJoiner` from the subsequent calculations / operations (I needed to perform some calculations on fields of the joined records and return a newly constructed object) and have it only return an array of the joined values. Then I could filter out the records that resulted in `null` values by checking those arrays.

Based on Matthias's J. Sax suggestion, I used the `0.10.2` version instead of the `0.10.1` which is compatible with broker version `0.10.1` and replace the whole `leftJoin` logic with inner join which removes the need for filtering out `null` values.